# WCF .NET4.6 TLS1.2 SSLNegotiation "The internal error state is 10013."

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, wcf-security, tls1.2

I have WCF service calls, which use authentication mode "UserNameForSslNegotiated" and which work perfectly, while TLS1.0 is enabled on the (Windows Server 2012) server.

When I disable TLS1.0, to leave just TLS1.2 on the server, the calls fail with the error "A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL server credential. The internal error state is 10013." in the System event log on the server.

On the client, the error is "The token provider cannot get tokens for target ..."

If I change the authentication mode to "UsernameOverTransport" the calls are fine with just TLS1.2, so the problem must be with SSL negotiation.

I've made no change to the certificate and private key.

The windows client and server are .NET4.6.1.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Any idea what algorithms your machines have configured for TLS? Have you enabled FIPS compliance?

Comment: On the WCF webserver, TLS1.2 Client and Server are enabled.  Additionally, TLS1.0 Client is enabled, which is necessary to do the username checking, during authentication, against a SqlMembershipProvider sqlserver DB on a separate server, which hasn't yet been updated for TLS1.2.

Comment: I haven't enabled FIPS compliance.